# How did i get oracle particular table's column history?

Tags: oracle

How did I get particular table's column history ?
e-g

```
table name :employee
column name     column adddate    column modifydate
empname           08/07/15            09/08/15  
empcode           08/07/15            01/08/15
empsal            08/07/15            10/09/15
```

when particular data type or its length or new column(field) added to a table.

Comment: Maybe you need DDL triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using DDL triggers if you want to track schema object level details , also it is better to fine tune your auditing.

create table .ddl_audit
 (
    os_user_name     varchar2(255),
    current_user     varchar2(255),
    host                varchar2(255),
    terminal            varchar2(255),
    ddl_type         varchar2(255),
    owner            varchar2(30),
    object_type      varchar2(255),
    object_name      varchar2(128),
    system_event        varchar2(20),
    ddl_sql_stmt        varchar2(2000),
    ddl_date         timestamp
 );

create or replace TRIGGER audit_ddl_trg AFTER ddl ON .schema
  DECLARE
    sql_text ora_name_list_t;
    v_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
    retval pls_integer;
  BEGIN
    retval := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
    FOR i IN 1..retval
    LOOP
      v_stmt := v_stmt || sql_text(i);
    END LOOP;
    INSERT
    INTO .DDL_AUDIT
      (
        os_user_name,
        current_user,
        host,
        terminal,
        ddl_type,
        owner,
        object_type,
        object_name,
        system_event,
        ddl_sql_stmt,
        ddl_date
      )
      VALUES
      (
        sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER') ,
        sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') ,
        sys_context('USERENV','HOST') ,
        sys_context('USERENV','TERMINAL') ,
        ora_dict_obj_type,
        ora_dict_obj_owner,
        ora_dict_obj_type,
        ora_dict_obj_name,
        ora_sysevent,
        v_stmt,
        SYSTIMESTAMP
      );
  END;

-- use same app schema to 
create table t1(c1 int,c2 varchar(10));

-- make more changes

alter table t1 add c3 varchar2(50);

query the ddl_audit table sorted by ddl_date ...

**Note:- Make sure to grant necessary privileges.**

Comment: Thank you for valuable reply.